# Write output from a function in powershell command window

Tags: function, powershell

I have a GUI and it calls a function depending on the button pressed. I would like for the output of the function to show in the powershell command window when I run the GUI. The code below contains 5 buttons, when I run the powershell script and click on any of the 5 buttons, nothing happens and it just hangs, until i close out of it.

```
    # This is code for the GUI ▼
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '406,414'
$Form.text                       = "Post DC Patching Checker"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$Check_NetLogon                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Check_NetLogon.text             = "Check Netlogon"
$Check_NetLogon.width            = 340
$Check_NetLogon.height           = 50
$Check_NetLogon.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,17)
$Check_NetLogon.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Ping                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Ping.text                       = "Ping Servers / Workstations"
$Ping.width                      = 340
$Ping.height                     = 50
$Ping.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(16,97)
$Ping.Font                       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$ShowReplication                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$ShowReplication.text            = "Show Replication"
$ShowReplication.width           = 340
$ShowReplication.height          = 50
$ShowReplication.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(16,183)
$ShowReplication.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$DiskSpace                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$DiskSpace.text                  = "Disk Space"
$DiskSpace.width                 = 340
$DiskSpace.height                = 50
$DiskSpace.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,267)
$DiskSpace.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$CheckDNSsuffix                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$CheckDNSsuffix.text             = "Check IP Configuration"
$CheckDNSsuffix.width            = 340
$CheckDNSsuffix.height           = 50
$CheckDNSsuffix.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,350)
$CheckDNSsuffix.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Check_NetLogon,$Ping,$ShowReplication,$DiskSpace,$CheckDNSsuffix))

$Check_NetLogon.Add_Click({ CheckNetLogon })
$Ping.Add_Click({ PingServersAndWorkstations })
$ShowReplication.Add_Click({ ShowReplicationOnServers })
$DiskSpace.Add_Click({ ShowDiskSpace })
$CheckDNSsuffix.Add_Click({ ShowIPconfig })
# This is code for the GUI ▲


# Check the netlogon service ▼
function CheckNetLogon { 
    $netLogon =Get-Service -DisplayName netlogon 
        if ($netLogon.Status -eq "Running"){
        $netLogon.DisplayName + 'Service is running already'}
    }
# Check the netlogon service ▲


# Ping's several workstations and servers ▼
function PingServersAndWorkstations {
        ping test2
        ping test3
        ping test4
        ping test5
    }
# Ping's several workstations and servers ▲


# Shows replication ▼
function ShowReplicationOnServers {
        repadmin /showrepl
    } 
# Shows replication ▲


# Shows disk space ▼
function ShowDiskSpace {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk  | 
        Select-Object -Property DeviceID, DriveType, VolumeName, 
        @{L='FreeSpaceGB';E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace /1GB)}}
    }
# Shows replication ▲



# Shows IP config ▼
function ShowIPconfig {
        ipconfig
   }
# Shows IP config ▲

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `$Ping`? This will not work unless `$Ping` is not `$null`

Comment: Also, please remove the version specific tags unless this question is specific to a certain version of PowerShell

Comment: What could i put for the definition if im trying to get the output of ping

Comment: `$Ping` should be a windows forms object. The code above won't execute unless it is initialized. Is this all the code you have?

Comment: If `$Ping` is a variable that stores a form button, use `$Form.Controls.Add($Ping)`. What are `Test5` .. `Test2`?

Comment: @Theo they appear to represent hosts to ping

Comment: Ive added the windows form object for $ping

Theo - Yes, they are hosts that are being ping'd

Comment: Move `$Form.Controls.Add($Ping)` down because you cannot add the control until you have defined it. Also, it is just one button, so don't use `AddRAnge` there

Comment: Ive tried that, ive added my entire powershell script to the window above.

Comment: I would go for a textbox inside the form and display the resulting output in there. Have a look at this blog [Displaying Output in a GUI Application](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/12/15/display-output-in-a-gui-application-copy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$formTest = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$formTest.Size = '406,414'
$formTest.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$formTest.text = "Post DC Patching Checker"

$buttonPing = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$formTest.Controls.Add($buttonPing)
$buttonPing.text = "Ping Servers / Workstations"
$buttonPing.Size = '340,50'
$buttonPing.location = '16, 97'
$buttonPing.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$buttonPing.Add_Click({
    $this.Enabled = $false
    'google.com', 'test1', 'test2' |
    ForEach-Object{
        Try{
        Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop| 
            Out-String | 
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor green
        }
        Catch{
            Write-Host $_ -fore Red
        }
    }
    $this.Enabled = $true
})
$formTest.ShowDialog()
```